# HTML embed audio file with poster image on both PCs and iOS

Tags: html, flash, audio, html5-audio

I am trying to embed an audio file that shows a picture in the background on a website. (Note before continuing: the website I am using is hosted by someone else, and I have to use their css, so I can adjust the html in the body, including inline css, but I cannot adjust the css itself. Also, I'm new to web programming, so please excuse any foolishness in this post.)

I have found several ways to do what I want that looks fine on PC browsers, but all of them fail at least partially on iOS devices. The three solutions that I have tried are:

1. jwplayer. Here the issue is that iOS is incompatible with flash, but it looks great on PC operating systems. The code looks like this:

   ```
   <span id="pod_video_1">&nbsp;</span>
   <script type="text/javascript">
       var pod_video_flashvars_1 = {
           file: "http%3A%2F%2Fpath%2Fto%2file.mp3",
           image: "http%3A%2F%2Fpath%2Fto%2image.jpg"
       };
       var pod_video_params_1 = {
           allowfullscreen: "true",
           allowscriptaccess: "always"};
       swfobject.embedSWF("https://path/mediaplayer.swf", "pod_video_1", "400", "300", "9.0.0", "", pod_video_flashvars_1, pod_video_params_1);
   </script>
   ```
2. HTML video tag. This one looks okay in PC operating systems (not as good as jwplayer though), and good on iPad. On iPhones, though, the issue I have with it is that it puts a huge play button on the poster image, which covers up the image (if I could force the play button on the image to be smaller, that would be ideal). The code:

   ```
   <video controls poster="http://path/to/image.jpg"> 
       <source src="http://path/to/file.mp3" type="video/mp4"> 
   </video>
   ```
3. HTML audio tag with a picture above it. Here the issue is that the audio bar looks is too big and gets cut off on the iPhone, but if I resize it manually, it gets screwed up on other devices. The code:

   ```
   <img src="http://path/to/image.jpg">
   <audio controls style="width: 400px; height: YYpx;"> 
       <source src="http://path/to/file.mp3" type="audio/mp3"> 
   </audio>
   ```

Does anyone know how to get past this difficulty, to get a nice display on both iOS devices and other operating systems?

Thank you very much for any help.